# Using Docker with firewalld

Tags: docker, firewalld

TL;DR Trying to masquerade everything from `Docker` with `firewalld` manually.

I just started to use `firewalld` on my Debian 10 machine since I want to learn how it works.

I have `Docker` installed on the host and I want to manage the firewall by myself to learn more about what Docker does, what rules etc. it applies when containers are created and how firewalld works.

Since Debian 10 uses `nftables` by default and use some kind of `iptables` wrapper to be able to use `iptables` commands to create firewall rules. `Docker` runs just fine when `--iptables` is enabled.

However I want to use `firewalld` with `nftables` backend and skip everything that has to do with `iptables` since it's just confusing. So in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service` I added `--iptables=false` so Docker doesn't mess with the firewall.
I flushed all the iptables rules etc. and all is good so far.

Now to my problem.

All containers can access the host and each other but not the internet.
Since they all are running on 172.17.0.0/16 and my host is on 192.168.9.0/24 I need to masquerade the traffic from the containers.

I can't find much information about managing the firewall manually when using Docker and since I'm new to firewalld I'm kind of just guessing.

My interfaces are as follows:

```
eno1 (main interface)
docker0 (docker bridge)
veth******* (one for each container)
```

all the `veth` interfaces are in the `docker0` bridge.

So I thought I could create a new zone called `docker` and masquerade everything from the `docker0` bridge.

```
~# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=docker
~# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --change-interface=docker0
~# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address=172.17.0.0/16 masquerade'
~# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Listing the active zones gives me this:

```
~# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
docker
  interfaces: docker0
public
  interfaces: eno1
```

I still can't access the internet from the containers.
I have no idea if this is the right way to go or what I'm missing.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firewalld, masquerading needs to be set on the zone which leads out to the Internet. In your case, that seems to be the `public` zone.

Comment: Of course.. I changed the masquerade rule to the public zone instead and now they can access the internet. Thank you!